# How can I bind the Ctrl-} key for a LaTeX command?

Tags: key-bindings, latex

When working in LaTeX (specifically, with AUCTeX), I want to bind the following functionality to the `C-{` and `C-}` keys:

- `C-{`: insert `\begingroup` followed by a newline
- `C-}`: insert `\endgroup` followed by a newline

As per [this thread on LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212156/add-key-binding-to-emacs-in-auctex-does-not-fully-work/212160#212160) I've tried the following:

```
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-{") "\\begingroup\n")
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-}") "\\endgroup\n")))
```

It doesn't work, however, and if I try `C-h k C-}` nothing happens.  How can I make my keybindings work?

I have tested the above behavior in at least three modes, Emacs-Lisp, LaTeX (AucTex) and XML mode.

I am using GNU Emacs 24 in Ubuntu 14.04.

**UPDATE 1**

I completely emptied my init file and then restarted emacs. The odd behavior persists.

**UPDATE 2**

*All* the proposed solutions, including my original one, has started to work.

I am without a clue.

Comment: It works for me provided that you've bound a function to it.  What is the behavior you are expecting?  Are you running Emacs in a terminal window, by any chance?

Comment: @Dan I was trying use this solution, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212160/14103. It did not work.

Comment: @Dan No, I am not using terminal mode.

Comment: Are you sure this key works in other programs? Sounds like your OS is intercepting this key for something.

Comment: After you open a fresh instance of Emacs, evaluate these two lines: `(load "auctex")` and then `(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-{") "\\begingroup\n")`.  Open a new LaTeX buffer.  Does `C-{` work now?

Comment: For future reference, you don't need to empty your init-file if you want to check whether a problem is present in stock Emacs. Just start Emacs via `emacs -Q`. This will prevent any customizations from being loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much more common to bind a key to a *command* rather than a string, although, as @Malabarba notes in the comment, you actually can bind a key to a string which is self-inserted (news to me, but it works!).

You can [define two new functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Functions.html) (note the [`interactive`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html) part, which makes them commands):

```
(defun insert-begin-group ()
  "Inserts \"\\begingroup\" followed by a newline."
  (interactive)
  (insert "\\begingroup\n"))

(defun insert-end-group ()
  "Inserts \"\\endgroup\" followed by a newline."
  (interactive)
  (insert "\\endgroup\n"))

(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-{") 'insert-begin-group)
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-}") 'insert-end-group)
```

To make sure they get bound after you load AUCTeX, you can adjust the code you were trying earlier:

```
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-{") 'insert-begin-group)
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-}") 'insert-end-group)))
```

Comment: Actually, binding a key to a string totally works. :-) The string is treated as a keyboard macro, which usually means it is inserted plainly.

Comment: @Malabarba: holy moly, you're right.  I never knew that.  I'll update the answer so it doesn't mislead.

Comment: This is "usually" equivalent, but not if one of the character-keys is bound to a non-usual behavior. In this specific example, if `TeX-electric-escape` is set to `t`, `\ ` is bound to `TeX-electric-macro` and the last newline will be used to confirm the input macro (and so not included in the buffer). `insert` is more robust, for code meant to be used in unspecified environments.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't wanna look like a jerk, but I just cannot understand in which way your answer seems to be better than mine? You posted essentially the same answer 6 minutes later, using function definitions instead of lambdas, then you added `eval-after-load` part from [another answer that OP showed to us](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212156/add-key-binding-to-emacs-in-auctex-does-not-fully-work/212160#212160). All this stuff is self-explanatory. Sorry, but this sort of behavior is *strongy* discourages users from answering anything.

Comment: @Mark: very sorry, that wasn't the intent.  I think the issue is that these materials are *not* always self-explanatory to a new user, and OP seems to be relatively new (though I could be wrong about that).  That's why I included the additional material explaining how to define a command and then bind it to a key.  Your answer definitely works (hence, I +1-ed it when I saw it), but for a new person, it strikes me as helpful to have a bit more explanation of what's going on (e.g., telling him what the `lambda` is all about).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to insert `\endgroup RET` into buffer, try this:

```
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-}")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (insert "\\endgroup\n")))
```

You also can do similar thing for <kbd>C-{</kbd> and `\begingroup RET`.

Comment: @Masroor: you can read up on [`lambda` functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/lambda.html) to see how this answer works.  (The short version: it's a function, but one without a name.)

Answer (score 1):

[ I am posting an answer, as I do not have enough reputation to post a comment. Feel free to delete this answer and turn it into a comment to the question. ]

As you are on Ubuntu, you can use the command line utility `xev` to test what X11 spits out when you press a certain key. If the key works with xev, it should be your window manager intercepting the key press, as @Malabarba already pointed out.

Comment: Welcome to mx.sx! Imo, your post looks like a good base for an answer, rather than a mere comment. Note that `xev` is available on any linux using X.org, which should be mostly any linux desktop.